# Full width horizontal rule in an ordered list

Tags: html, css

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spycho/J4b6Y/38/), you can see that the horizontal rule does not go all the way across (under the number). I want it to. I have tried using `list-style-position:inside;`, however this means that I cannot force the number to appear in the correct position (because of the floated left image). Is there an elegant way to do this using CSS, or do I have to resort to generating the numbering myself and then styling appropriately?

Comment: It probably varies from browser to browser. What are you using?

Comment: I should clarify, I require the `float:left;`. Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spycho/J4b6Y/38/) more similar to my actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the other answers to the question, it would seem that whilst there are ways of accomplishing this with CSS, there isn't an *elegant* way. As such, my prefered solution is to generate the numbering in the HTML and style appropriately. This can be trivial to do if the page is generated as a result of server side scripting.

I shall keep an eye out for more elegant ways of solving this with CSS and update this question if I find any.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 4**

Seems like Update 3 worked well on webkit but not FF... so it's time to use real CSS power.

http://jsfiddle.net/J4b6Y/122/

---

**UPDATE 3**

Now what about this

http://jsfiddle.net/J4b6Y/105/

---

**UPDATE 2**

http://jsfiddle.net/J4b6Y/48/

---

**UPDATE**

Try this if it works for you

http://jsfiddle.net/J4b6Y/33/

Comment: I think the OP is using Firefox.

Comment: The horizontal rule still doesn't appear under the list item numbers, so it does not solve the OP's issue.

Comment: Update 4 should be your answer hopefully.

Comment: It doesn't appear to work in IE8 and seems a bit overly complicated... I'm thinking it's probably better to just generate the numbering myself and style appropriately... It would be much simpler and cross-browser supported. Thoughts?

Comment: You can use a conditional comment for IE only, so that IE will use one of the methods suggested before, while with this method you will go good with every other browser. Choice it's up to you, I personally would rather have less html and more CSS, even if complicated. After all, it's complicated probably because you're not used to it, but I can assure you it's nothing difficult really.

Comment: Generating the numbers yourself anyway is really bad to me... if later you must rearrange the items or deleting/adding you have to change them all... either stick with the OL, CSS counter-increment, or a JS. And IE is easily fixable with a conditional style.

Comment: I know it's not difficult, but it is ugly and requires browser-specific hacks. Also, I would be automatically generating the numbering, not hard-coding it, so that method would be very simple. In fact, each li is generated from an ordered Django QuerySet, so this would be trivial. I was wondering if there was an elegant CSS solution to this problem, but it would appear not. Given the hackyness / questionable browser support of the proposed CSS solutions, I think the most elegant solution would be to automatically generate the numbering as HTML. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be well aware of the `list-style-position` property, so you should know why the horizontal rule will not span all the way under the bullet/number. The list has a padding on the left, pushing the list elements to the right. Their contents won't go out of their space :).

Here's how I got over the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/J4b6Y/14/

[EDIT]

Fix for webkit browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/J4b6Y/16/

[EDIT2]

Works in all browsers AND has valid HTML o_O http://jsfiddle.net/J4b6Y/37/

[EDIT3]

OK, here's another one... http://jsfiddle.net/J4b6Y/39/

Comment: Try your demo in a WebKit browser :(

Comment: Thank you, @thirtydot. I updated the reply to include a fixed version.

Comment: It works now, but your [HTML is invalid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net%2FJ4b6Y%2F16%2Fshow%2Flight%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Comment: Unfortunately, I really do need that image to be floated left. In the actual problem (rather than the example I gave), it's a div float left of another div.

Comment: @mingos that 3 edit is the same conclusion I just come up with.

Comment: @Jose indeed. I haven't checked your updated fiddle, sorry. Either way, Chrome refuses to work with it, as Spycho remarked.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you remove the hr tag and the floating image properties.

If you cannot set the image with css background, you can do the following:

HTML

```
<li>
    <img src="" alt="test"/>
    <p>Test</p>
</li>
```

CSS

```
li{
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    list-style-position:inside;
}
li p{
     display:inline-block;   
}
```

Also, if you can remove the p tag, you will save few bites.

Comment: I would rather use an hr tag than a bottom border as I feel it is more semantically correct. Also, I need to float the image. My actual situation is a little more complex than the example I have and requires that image to be floated (actually, it's a div, floated left of another div).

Comment: Then you should give us the real code, not something barely similar, since each situation is different and may require different approaches.

Comment: Sorry. Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spycho/J4b6Y/38/) more similar to the actual situation. You can have the actual code if you want, but it's huge. I thought it would be easier for people to understand if I gave an simplified example of the problem.